# Can stdout, stderr always tee to a regular file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can I configure bash on Linux to write a copy of all stdout and stderr to a regular file, without having to specify the redirection for each command?

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`script`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) to create a log of your shell session

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a script, I'd recommend write a shell function and redirect its output. You won't have to redirect each command of that function then. I hardly see any meaning in redirections in interactive shell anyway.

Comment: I was pleased to find bash 4.1 offers writing command history to syslog.

I'm hoping for that level of convenience in logging the output and error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec` command, if not given a command to execute, will apply its redirections to the current shell. In my testing, however, this does not seem to work that well for pipes. I'd suggest using a subshell, which you can redirect normally.

```
(
   echo hello
   echo hello err >&2
) 2>&1 | tee logfile.txt
```

If you only need a transcript, not a continuous tee, `exec >& logfile` might work.

Also, a traditional trick is to use a remote login tool (ssh or telnet) piped to tee to create a log of an interactive session. [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) also supports logging.